# Synapse - Can't properly deploy SQL linked server

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-synapse

Hello I’m having a problem when I try to deploy my Synapse workspace to another environment (eg. Development to Test).
The problem is that the SQL linked services doesn’t seems to deploy properly. The first screenshot is from the development synapse and the second screenshot form test. As you can see the settings of the linked service are completely different.

**Development**

[image: Linked service development]

**Test enviroment**

[image: Linked service Test]

I’m using the standard synapse deployment task in my DevOps pipeline

```
        - task: Synapse workspace deployment@1
      displayName: 'Synpase deployment task for workspace: syn$(name)$(environment)'
      inputs:
        TemplateFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(cicd_synapse_workspace_origin)/TemplateForWorkspace.json'
        ParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(cicd_synapse_workspace_origin)/TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json'
        AzureSubscription: '${{ parameters.sercon }}'
        ResourceGroupName: 'rg-$(name)-$(environment)'
        TargetWorkspaceName: syn$(name)$(environment)
        OverrideArmParameters: '
        -ls_sq_mark_connectionString  $(Connectionstring)
```

Whereby I overwrite the linked service with a variable form the DevOps library (it contains the following code “("Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=databaseserver;Initial Catalog=database")”

The thing I noticed when I looked into the JSON file (TemplateForWorkspace.json) that the linked service is defined as follow:

```
        "ls_sq_mark_connectionString": {
        "type": "secureString",
        "metadata": "Secure string for 'connectionString' of 'ls_sq_mark'"
    },
```

Maybe the problem is, is that it's suddenly a securestring? But i have no idea how to fixed this issue.